# how do you crash a machine with infinite loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops

how do you crash a machine with infinite loop in ruby?

Comment: We do not crash machines.

Comment: Only a script kiddie would want to know the answer to that question

Answer (score 7):

An infinite loop alone can't crash a "machine", unless it gets 100% CPU time (which no sane OS will allow).

You can create an infinite loop which will eat up memory without letting it be garbage collected, but this will just crash the current process.

You could instead create processes, which create other processes recursively ([a fork bomb](https://github.com/mcandre/forkbombs)). This will manage to slow down and eventually crash a "machine", but any sane server will have a limitation on how many processes a user can spawn.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux (or equivalant), you can keep opening files and never close them - at some point - you will start seeing "Too many open files" error - this can also hinder opening of new network connections.  This can happen if one has not reviewed open file limits on the system and working with default settings.

You can also keep creating files with lot of data in the OS partition, and fill up the disk space which can eventually lead to unresponsive system.  This can happen if you application creates too many log entries and you forget to rotate the files.